# Eclipse 2021-06 Java editor surrounds past with escape characters on copy and paste

Tags: eclipse

I am using Eclipse 2021-06 Java editor and when I do a cut and paste it surrounds the past with escape characters. Is there a fix for this? My example is:

Original:

```
String selectQry1 = ("SELECT DISTINCT csm_patient.pat_id, pat_surname, pat_other_names," +
                " pat_dob, pat_archived, pat_number, " +
                " min(csm_patient_clinic.pat_cli_start_date) startDate, pat_gender " +
                " FROM csm_patient, csm_patient_clinic " + 
                " WHERE csm_patient.cli_id = ? " +
                    " AND csm_patient.cd_archived IS NULL " +
                    " AND csm_patient.pat_id = csm_patient_clinic.pat_id " +
                " GROUP BY csm_patient.pat_surname, csm_patient.pat_other_names, csm_patient.pat_id;");
```

Copy:

```
SELECT DISTINCT csm_patient.pat_id, pat_surname, pat_other_names," +
                " pat_dob, pat_archived, pat_number, " +
                " min(csm_patient_clinic.pat_cli_start_date) startDate, pat_gender " +
                " FROM csm_patient, csm_patient_clinic " + 
                " WHERE csm_patient.cli_id = ? " +
                    " AND csm_patient.cd_archived IS NULL " +
                    " AND csm_patient.pat_id = csm_patient_clinic.pat_id " +
                " GROUP BY csm_patient.pat_surname, csm_patient.pat_other_names, csm_patient.pat_id;
```

Paste over the "SELECT" to ";" in:

```
String selectQry2 = ("SELECT DISTINCT csm_patient.pat_id, pat_surname, pat_other_names, " +
                    " pat_dob, pat_archived, pat_number, " +
                    " min(csm_patient_clinic.pat_cli_start_date) startDate, pat_gender " +
                " FROM csm_patient, csm_patient_clinic " +
                " WHERE csm_patient.cli_id = ? " +
                " AND csm_patient.pat_id = csm_patient_clinic.pat_id " +
                " GROUP BY csm_patient.pat_surname, csm_patient.pat_other_names, csm_patient.pat_id;");
```

Gives:

```
String selectQry2 = ("SELECT DISTINCT csm_patient.pat_id, pat_surname, pat_other_names,\" +\r\n"
                + "             \" pat_dob, pat_archived, pat_number, \" +\r\n"
                + "             \" min(csm_patient_clinic.pat_cli_start_date) startDate, pat_gender \" +\r\n"
                + "             \" FROM csm_patient, csm_patient_clinic \" + \r\n"
                + "             \" WHERE csm_patient.cli_id = ? \" +\r\n"
                + "                 \" AND csm_patient.cd_archived IS NULL \" +\r\n"
                + "                 \" AND csm_patient.pat_id = csm_patient_clinic.pat_id \" +\r\n"
                + "             \" GROUP BY csm_patient.pat_surname, csm_patient.pat_other_names, csm_patient.pat_id;");
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Java editor has a "Smart Insert Mode" (Edit > Smart Insert Mode) which tries to do helpful things when pasting in to Java code.

One of the things it can do is add escapes when inserting in to strings.

You can control smart insert actions in the "Java > Editor > Typing" page in the Preferences. The "In string literals" section covers actions for inserting in strings. "Escape text when pasting into a string literal" is what is doing this.

You can also just turn of smart insert on the Edit menu.

Answer (score 1):

Disable smart insert in edit menu.